# Best way to track CPU load % on a SGE cluster in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, sungridengine, ganglia

I'd like to analyze the CPU load history to measure the efficiency of our algorithms. What is the best way to track CPU load % on a SGE cluster in GCE?  Google cloud console tracks it, but does not make it downloadable as far as I can tell. SGE tracks load internally but it seems rather basic. My guess is Ganglia will be the route to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Google Cloud Monitoring API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-monitoring/) which was [recently released](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/07/introducing-google-cloud-monitoring-read-api.html) to track CPU load in your instances.